# Conversion of wchar_t into char

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I am trying to convert `wchar_t` to `char` using `wcstombs`. And it works fine if only 1 value is converted but when more than 1 value is converted it gives unexpected results.
These are two `wchar_t` values which I want to convert:

```
wchar_t szBuf[BUFF_LEN];
wchar_t szBuf1[BUFF_LEN];
```

and converting using `wcstombs`:

```
char user[]=""; 
int  length = wcstombs(user,szBuf,250);
char pass[]="";
int  length1 = wcstombs(pass,szBuf1,250);
```

say if I have **alice** in `szBuf` and **alice123** in `szBuf1` then `pass` will give the correct value but `user` will have a value like **aalice123**. What is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your destination buffers are too small.

`char user[] = "";` equals `char user[1] = "";`. This means that you will write to unallocated space and it is *undefined behaviour*. This is very bad, because there are no guarantees what will happen.

Specify size for your destionation buffers: `char user[250] = "";`

Answer (score 3):

You're invoking Undefined Behaviour, because you're writing outside of the buffer bounds. Your `user` and `pass` buffers are each of length `1` (they're arrays initialised by a copy of `""`). So you're happily writing to random memory and anything could happen.